# R: How to create groups based on frequency found together by another variable?

Tags: r

I have a `dataset` with about 300 different category codes (`X2`) that are each associated with a number (`X1`), which often repeats over different category codes and vice versa:

```
  X1   X2 
 1923 AA12 
 1923 AA28 
 1923 AA23 
 1348 AA12 
 1348 AB17 
 1348 AB08 
 9334 AA12 
 9334 AD02
```

etc.

I want to figure out how to create different groups, or buckets, of category codes that are most often found together based on the `X1` variables. I can't figure out a simple way to do this.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what format you're expecting, but I'd just paste the X1 and X2 columns together, then use `table` to give frequency counts. If you want to see the most common, just use the `sort` function to order it.

Assuming your data is in a data frame called `df`

```
sort(table(paste0(df$X1, "_", df$X2)))
```

If you're intention is the give labels in the original dataframe to identify if they're frequently found together, please provide more information. Because there's no consistent way to identify "most often found together" unless you literally mean you just want to classify those with the single highest frequency.